# Are these lines of code in C programming the same

Tags: c

Are these 2 lines of code the same ??

**line 1:**

```
void (**foo)(int)
```

**line 2**

```
void *(*foo)(int)
```

Kindly help me understand on what is happening.

Comment: [https://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28**foo%29%28int%29](https://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28**foo%29%28int%29), [https://cdecl.org/?q=void+*%28*foo%29%28int%29](https://cdecl.org/?q=void+*%28*foo%29%28int%29)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not the same.

```
void (**foo)(int);
```

`foo` is a pointer to a pointer to a function that takes an `int` parameter and returns `void`.

```
void *(*foo)(int):
```

`foo` is a pointer to a function that takes an `int` parameter and returns a pointer to `void`.

Postfix operators like `()` and `[]` have higher precedence than unary `*`, so

```
T *a[N];    // a is an array of pointer to T
T (*a)[N];  // a is a pointer to an array of T

T *f();     // f is a function returning pointer to T
T (*f)();   // f is a pointer to a function returning T
```